# lerna link: Cannot find module '@lerna/create/command

Tags: lerna, monorepo

I'm using lerna. I've tried versions 3.22.1, 3.21.0, and 3.20.0.

I'm getting the following error every time I run `npx lerna link`:

```
Cannot find module '@lerna/create/command'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Usuario\project\node_modules\lerna\index.js
- C:\Users\Usuario\project\node_modules\lerna\cli.js
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by:

- Deleting all the `yarn.lock` files: `find . -name yarn.lock -delete`
- Adding this flag to `bootstrap`: `lerna boostrap --force-local`

Comment: I think the `--force-local` has nothing to do with that fix, as it will only force symbolic links from the lerna managed local packages, not its internal dependencies. It seems to be related with your windows environment and the PATH setup. The removal of the lock files may have trigger a clean installation and fixed your local PATH for you.

Comment: The only option where `force-local` could have actually helped is when there's a local version mismatch. In that case, you should confirm the `version` tag from the `package.json` files from each module, and where they are referenced.